# How can I force url friendly filenames when using CarrierWaveDirect in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using CarrierWaveDirect to handle image uploads. I have users uploading files that have filenames which are not url friendly such as:

`one arizona center.jpg`

When I find the corresponding photo object in the console the path comes up as:

```
p.image.path
=> "uploads/8da5058e-6037-41d4-b311-094aaabf5469/one arizona center.jpg"
```

That's all good because I can display the image with the image_url method and get:

`.../uploads/84cf32df-40eb-462b-88cb-ecc9452d2727/one%20arizona%20center.jpg`

The problem is if the photo object is updated. In my case an admin user has to approve the photo. The object simply has a boolean field for 'approved' which gets toggled. When I run:

`p.update_attribute(:approved,true)`

The path becomes:

```
p.image.path
=> "uploads/8da5058e-6037-41d4-b311-094aaabf5469/one%2520arizona%2520center.jpg"
```

Here is what the actual controller action looks like:

```
  def approve
    photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    status = photo.update_attribute :approved, true

    respond_to do |wants|
      ...
    end
  end
```

Here is a sample from the server log:

```
Started POST "/admin/photos/7/approve" for 199.223.122.34 at 2013-10-29 20:46:18 +0000
2013-10-29T20:46:18.589054+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Admin::PhotosController#approve as */*
2013-10-29T20:46:18.589054+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}
2013-10-29T20:46:18.598598+00:00 app[web.1]:   Photo Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "7"]]
2013-10-29T20:46:18.603564+00:00 app[web.1]:    (4.6ms)  BEGIN
2013-10-29T20:46:18.610299+00:00 app[web.1]:   Photo Load (3.8ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
2013-10-29T20:46:18.613560+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.3ms)  UPDATE "photos" SET "approved" = 't', "image" = '0289da71-14cd-46c1-a42c-feff92ac0303/Screen%2520Shot%25202013%252010%252029%2520at%25201.44.20%2520PM.png', "updated_at" = '2013-10-29 20:46:18.610428' WHERE "photos"."id" = 7
```

Notice that in the final SQL statement that the 'image' attribute is updated as well as the 'approved' attribute. The non-safe url is now escaped in the local database leading to broken images on the site when supplying the image_url method to an image tag.

Is there any way to easily force url safe filenames with CarrierWaveDirect?

For further information my uploader is as follows:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

end
```

And the model with the uploader mounted looks like this:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :business, foreign_key: "eponic_id", primary_key: "business_id"
  attr_accessible :image, :description
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  scope :approved, where(approved: true)
  scope :pending, where(approved: false)
end
```

**UPDATE:**

We couldn't pinpoint the exact cause of the issue. Apparently, CarrierWave or CarrierWaveDirect has a callback that is getting called when I run update_attribute on the uploader's parent model. As a work around I'm simply using 'update_column' to skip rails' callback chain. I've filed an issue on github:
https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct/issues/113

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that the image url is escaped again and again each time you submit the update form. This just suggests that you need to have the unescaped URL available in the form.

If the user submits a url of `'images/my image name.jpg'` they should never see `'images/my%20image%20%name.jpg'` when the form refreshes, even though this is how you store it internally. You should decode it for display--just pass it through `URI.decode` when you are outputting it to your form.

(This is different from having an HTML-unsafe string in your form--this is literally just a question of *representing* user input exactly as it was originally without URI encoding. A `<` character, for example, would still become a `&lt;` entity on your page, but not a `%3C` escape sequence. Rails should handle the HTML-safety automatically--just be absolutely sure and try some tags in the URL.)

Edit: not wanting to lead you up some XSS garden path, I tried it out...

```
%input{ type: :text, value: URI.decode("http://%3Cscript%3Ealert(1);%3C/script%3E.jpg") }
```

It's fine. It appears in the textbox as `http://<script>alert(1);</script>.jpg`, but in source it is HTML-safe as expected.

**Based on your comments** I've decided to set up a little app from scratch and see what happens. It's a plain Rails 4 app. I've brought in the carrierwave gem and created a default uploader. (I'll look at `carrierwave_direct` in a separate step). I create a `Photo` model as follows:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :description, :approved
  mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader
end
```

The `PhotoUploader` class just looks like this (all defaults from the generator):

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Before I go near any forms let's try and make a `Photo` instance from the console, re-read it, update an attribute, and see what happens to our path. I've got a file called `picture of neil.jpg` sitting in the root directory of the app.

```
2.0.0-p195 :001 > p = Photo.new
 => #<Photo id: nil, image: nil, description: nil, approved: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p195 :002 > p.image.class
 => PhotoUploader
```

All good so far. Let's fake a form hash and then give the uploader a file handle to the data, then save.

```
2.0.0-p195 :012 > p.image = { file_name: 'picture of neil.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpeg', size: File.size('picture of neil.jpg') }
 => {:file_name=>"picture of neil.jpg", :content_type=>"image/jpeg", :size=>53637} 
2.0.0-p195 :013 > p.image = File.open 'picture of neil.jpg'
 => #<File:picture of neil.jpg>
2.0.0-p195 :014 > p.save!
  (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "photos" ("created_at", "image", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 18:03:49 UTC +00:00], ["image", "picture_of_neil.jpg"], ["updated_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 18:03:49 UTC +00:00]]
  (1.6ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Now if I look in `public/uploaders/photo/image/1`, there I am, in a file called `picture_of_neil.jpg`. Carrierwave has sanitized the name but never mind. It hasn't converted the spaces to `%20` characters or anything like that.

I'm going to tweak the file name sanitizer regex to accept spaces and try it all again:

```
2.0.0-p195 :015 > CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+ ]/
 => /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+ ]/ 
2.0.0-p195 :016 > p = Photo.new
 => #<Photo id: nil, image: nil, description: nil, approved: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p195 :017 > p.image = { file_name: 'picture of neil.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpeg', size: File.size('picture of neil.jpg') }
 => {:file_name=>"picture of neil.jpg", :content_type=>"image/jpeg", :size=>53637} 
2.0.0-p195 :018 > p.image = File.open 'picture of neil.jpg'
 => #<File:picture of neil.jpg> 
2.0.0-p195 :019 > p.save!
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "photos" ("created_at", "image", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 18:12:09 UTC +00:00], ["image", "picture of neil.jpg"], ["updated_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 18:12:09 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

Cool, it saved the file with spaces in the name, no problem. If I tweak another attribute and save it again, it's fine as expected. Calling `update_attributes` is also fine.

`carrierwave_direct` uses `:fog` so before I do anything else I'll switch over to using fog (in its excellent mock mode) and try everything I've just done again. My new carrierwave initializer looks like this:

```
Fog.mock!

S3_CREDENTIALS = { provider:              'AWS',
                   region:                'eu-west-1',
                   aws_access_key_id:     'MOCKKEYMOCKKEY', 
                   aws_secret_access_key: 'MOCKSECRETMOCKSECRET' }

S3_DIRECTORY = 'mock_bucket'

# If you're using Fog in mock mode, you have to create an in-memory directory.
Fog::Storage.new(S3_CREDENTIALS).directories.create(key: S3_DIRECTORY, public: false) if Fog.mocking?

CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+ ]/

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = S3_CREDENTIALS
  config.fog_directory   = S3_DIRECTORY
end
```

Now I'll go through the steps to create a `Photo` instance again and see what happens. I won't repeat the console output because it is identical. Now I can call `p.image.url` and see what fog gives me back:

```
2.0.0-p195 :005 > p.image.url
 => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mock_bucket/uploads/photo/image/5/picture%20of%20neil.jpg"
```

Ok! This is exactly what we expect. The path saved with the Photo instance *does not contain* these `%20` characters; it contains spaces. The URL, however, has been escaped. This is all good. What happens if I update the description?

```
2.0.0-p195 :006 > p.update_attributes description: "A picture of me in a hat"
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "photos" SET "description" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "photos"."id" = 5  [["description", "A picture of me in a hat"], ["updated_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 18:29:34 UTC +00:00]]
   (2.1ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
2.0.0-p195 :007 > p.reload
  Photo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
 => #<Photo id: 5, image: "picture of neil.jpg", description: "A picture of me in a hat", approved: nil, created_at: "2013-10-29 18:26:57", updated_at: "2013-10-29 18:29:34"> 
2.0.0-p195 :008 > p.image.url
 => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mock_bucket/uploads/photo/image/5/picture%20of%20neil.jpg"
```

Still all good. Now, *if somehow the file name was set to the url and not the original file name*, you can see how this would repeatedly get escaped and re-escaped. But as you say--you are only updating one field.

Let's bring in `carrierwave_direct` to see what it does. My `PhotoUploader` class now looks like this:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
end
```

I've gone through the documented steps to the letter to create an upload form.

**ARGH**, at this point I'm stumped because it doesn't seem to play nice with Fog in mock mode. It directs me to the real s3 servers, so the round trip to update my new model can't happen. Sorry. I'll try the same things later via the console, when I have some more time.

**OK**, got it working via the console. Hopefully enough to see what's going on. I've had to mute the validations, but look below--I'm reproducing the behaviour you're seeing.

```
2.0.0-p195 :027 > class CarrierWaveDirect::Validations::ActiveModel::FilenameFormatValidator < ::ActiveModel::EachValidator
2.0.0-p195 :028?>    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
2.0.0-p195 :029?>     end
2.0.0-p195 :030?>   end
 => nil 
2.0.0-p195 :031 > class CarrierWaveDirect::Validations::ActiveModel::RemoteNetUrlFormatValidator < ::ActiveModel::EachValidator
2.0.0-p195 :032?>    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
2.0.0-p195 :033?>     end
2.0.0-p195 :034?>   end
 => nil 
2.0.0-p195 :035 > p = Photo.new
 => #<Photo id: nil, image: nil, description: nil, approved: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p195 :036 > p.image = { file_name: 'picture of neil.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpeg' }
 => {:file_name=>"picture of neil.jpg", :content_type=>"image/jpeg"} 
2.0.0-p195 :037 > p.image = File.open 'picture of neil.jpg'
 => #<File:picture of neil.jpg> 
2.0.0-p195 :038 > p.save!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Photo Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."image" = '1383074454-35950-4053/picture%2520of%2520neil.jpg' LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO "photos" ("created_at", "image", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 19:20:56 UTC +00:00], ["image", "1383074454-35950-4053/picture%2520of%2520neil.jpg"], ["updated_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 19:20:56 UTC +00:00]]
   (2.5ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
2.0.0-p195 :039 > p.image.url
 => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mock_bucket/uploads/1383074454-35950-4053/picture%252520of%252520neil.jpg"
```

Obviously this url is wrong--for whatever reason, it has been escaped once too many times. Note that I'm not seeing this happen repeatedly on the update of attributes. What I would add is that the `carrierwave_direct` documentation says that you have to set `image.key` when creating that object, e.g.

```
2.0.0-p195 :048 > p.image.key = "1383074454-35950-4053/picture%20of%20neil.jpg"
 => "1383074454-35950-4053/picture%20of%20neil.jpg"
```

This works fine and the url is not doubly escaped. Are you doing this in your creation step, or are you using the muiltipart-form approach that standard carrierwave would use?

Comment: That's the issue though. I'm never outputting this to a form. I simply have a route /photos/approve/:id. All we do in the method is Photo.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:approved, true) but this is subsequently generating this SQL: (1.7ms) UPDATE "photos" SET "approved" = 't', "image" = '02216914-1e9e-4b63-8ae6-80e24cb87f7a/5918%25201%2520photo.jpg', "updated_at" = '2013-10-29 05:31:31.779058' WHERE "photos"."id" = 302

Comment: I have no idea why the "image" attribute is being updated during the photo.update_attribute(:approved, true).

Comment: Could you post your model (at least the validations and any lifecycle hooks?)

Comment: Added it. Nothing too fancy going on there. I've also posted this on github issues for carrierwave direct as I'm wondering if there is a bug here.

Comment: I've used Carrierwave a fair bit recently, I'll generate a very simple app and see if I run into the same thing.

Comment: Wow -- thanks for all of your help! Well here is a sample of the form: https://gist.github.com/jimjeffers/7222039 but its important to note that the image uploads are fine once this process completes. In the admin area photos are rendering with the correct single escaped url. It's only on that update to the parent model of the uploader that the url becomes twice escaped and stored this way in the database.

Comment: Here's an export of the current log so you can see the actual request and the subsequent queries: https://gist.github.com/jimjeffers/7222344 It has to be some internal code in CWD or CW that is escaping the key causing it to become a dirty attribute. Strange thing is I'm not calling 'save' just update_attribute. Maybe if I use write_attr? We shouldn't have to do this though.

Comment: Here's an idea for a terrible hack: you COULD put some known meaningless code on the end of every image URL, e.g. `?codecheck=%20`, then do a `URI.decode` on the before_save hook if its found to be `?codecheck=%2520`.

Comment: I think it must be down to a save hook in CWD re-encoding the URL. (I wonder what hooks it adds.)

Comment: Your upload form looks fine anyway.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I've upvoted your answer but I can't mark it as correct because we haven't been able to solve it. If I ever find out anything else I'll get in touch with a solution in case you want to update your answer at later time.

Comment: No problem, drop me a comment if you eventually figure it out.